# Is there a function that can count issues filtered by projects of JIRA in Confluence plugin?

Tags: java, jira, confluence

I'm now working on a Confluence plugin that search JIRA issues to display and filter them with project name. And I want to get the number of issues filtered by their project names. The question is, is there a simple way to get that number?

I've tried JIRA REST API's ***/search*** endpoint along with ***maxResults=0***, but it takes too long until i can get the number.

I searched for solutions but most of them are for plugins on JIRA.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not well conversant with JIRA and Confluence. I found below approaches by digging a little

- Confluence can communicate with JIRA using JQL(JIRA Query language).

Have you tried using JQL to get list of all issues filtered by project name? You can program to count the number of issues returned.

- JAVA
  You can use the below function from the [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/DAC/javadoc/jira/4.4.1/reference/com/atlassian/jira/issue/IssueManager.html#getIssueCountForProject(java.lang.Long))

  **public abstract long getIssueCountForProject (Long projectId)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I've tried JQL with maxResults=0, but the time it process was too long, i don't know why this happens or how to solve it. But the getIssueCountForProject seems can do the job, I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @NuttyShady :
Did getIssueCountForProject  work for you?

Comment: It didn't work for me, I'm trying another way to solve it。 Thank you soooo much!

Comment: @NuttyShady: If you find a good solution, please post the same here